How to access router outside of Vue component in Vue 3?
Let's say I use in my Vue component a helper function that doesn't take any arguments:
import { getFoo } from 'src/utils/foo'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const fooBar = getFoo()
  }
(...)

src/utils/foo:
export function getFoo() {
  // I need to access Vue router here
  return 'bar'
}

How do I access Vue Router in getFoo function without passing it explicitly as argument?
(and without importing router file directly, as it contains code that breaks HMR)
I tried useRouter() and provide/inject but it returns undefined:
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

export function getFoo() {
  // I need to access Vue router here

  // attempt nr 1
  const router = useRouter() // returns undefined

  // attempt nr 2
  const router2 = inject('router') // returns undefined (I already did app.provide('router', router) in my main.ts)
  console.log(hasInjectionContext()) // returns "false", why?

  return 'bar'
}

Alternatively, what are other ways of providing truly global variables in Vue 3?

Router definition is not shown. You're already supposed to have router variable in router module. If you don't, you should do this

I don't want to import router, I want to expose it as a global variable, so that I don't have to import it every time.

You should be fine using useRouter outside the component as long as the function is called in setup() {}. Did you remember to use app.use(router)?

Yes, I have app.use(router), router works.

do you use any async code in the setup?

@EstusFlask useRouter should work since called synced from setup, probably we don't see the whole code and there's no chance to debug. afaik useRouter is inject(routerSymbol)

@AlexanderNenashev Yes, useRouter() returns inject(routerKey) which is undefined in my case. Any idea why? I have some async functions but they should not block the setup function.

I've rewritten getFoo to a composable and useRouter() still returns undefined when used inside getFoo.

@van_folmert You only need to import router in uncommon places or a store. Please, provide a way to reproduce, it's not reproducible with code you posted.  app.use(router) makes sure useRouter work the way you'd expect. As long as there's no await or other async code in getFoo, there's no problem with this. It should behave similarly to the direct use of useRouter() in setup

@EstusFlask Indeed, it works in a simple synchronous code. But when I was calling getFoo/useRouter i.e. on a button click, useRouter was returning undefined. I've solved it by moving useRouter() outside of getFoo function in my composable.

I've figured it out. Apparently, useRouter doesn't work properly when called asynchronously. As a workaround, useRouter can be called synchronously in a composable:
import {
  useRouter
} from 'vue-router'

export default function useFoo() {
  const router = useRouter()

  function getFoo() {
    // const router = useRouter() // do NOT call useRouter here!
    console.log(router) // router is accessible!

    return 'bar'
  }

  return {
    getFoo
  }
}

and used in component:
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const {
      getFoo
    } = useFoo() // synchronous call

    const foo = getFoo() // works synchronously

    const onButtonClick = () => {
      // can be used asynchronously as well (previous attempts were not working asynchronously)
      const fooAsync = getFoo()
    }
  }
})


as i said it's an async problem
